# Old iPad not charging after no use for a year

Tags: ipad, battery

I have an old iPad and want to give it to a friend.

I plugged it in with a new lead that charges another 1st gen iPad I have, but it's not coming on.

It's not been used for about a year. It's been plugged in now for 20 minutes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end it came back after a few hours charging, has worked fine ever since.

Answer (score 7):

If it won't wake after several hours of charging, try another charger and let it sit there for up to 8 hours.

You have likely let the battery self discharge to a permanently harmful level, but in most cases you can get it to trickle charge enough so that it will boot again and be of limited use depending on how long the battery was in a harmfully low voltage situation.

It may never boot again, but that depends more on how healthy the battery was when it entered storage since a year usually won't kill a new battery but will put a huge dent into it's usability.

Comment: I bet every store Apple runs has several people that would tell you that and much more. Like http://www.apple.com/batteries/ - they say a monthly charge is best, but for long term storage I like to charge it to 80% and get it out for a top off back to 80% every 6 months and to use it for a day or two once a year to ensure it drains and then charges fully before putting it into storage. But sometimes we forget or someone loses track of an old device...

Answer (score 1):

I have a first generation iPad that I hadn’t charged in 4-6 months, it took about an hour before the battery icon came up but it’s charging just fine now.  The hard part these days is finding the old style power cord.